# How to get and change article in joomla before rendreing

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

Friends, tell me about the issue.
Is it possible to receive content in joomla before it is given to the browser.

In article, I want to make a shortcode like this  [[1, 2, 3]].
During page rendering I want to get an article, find a shortcode, open it and replace this shortcode with content that will be return by my function.
And only then it will retun the content to the browser.

Comment: Try to look at `onContentBeforeDisplay` event.

Comment: Thank you. Will try

Comment: @ВикторГоловко You might like to post your question on the Joomla Stack Exchange site to gain the attention of a more dedicated audience. Note, in your **Administrator** -> **Help** tab, the 2nd last item says **Stack Exchange** <-- this is where the Joomla team encourages you to post your Joomla-specific questions and issues when you need support.  Not only is there a dedicated audience there to offer support, when future researchers are hunting for Joomla solutions -- the answers will inevitably be there too.  Tidy, right?